# Visual Studio 2015 MySql LinQ to Entities Get generated query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2015

I am using MySql LinQ to entities with Visual Studio. The code works except for the part that is commented out.  That works with SQL but not with MySQL. Does anyone know the MySql equivalent of the code that is commented out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace TestMySql_Nuget_etc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            worldEntities db = new worldEntities();
            var countries = from c in db.countries
                            where c.Name.StartsWith("A")
                            select c;
            //string query = ((ObjectQuery)countries.ToTraceString());
            foreach(var c in countries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using? With EF6 you can use `var query = countries.ToString();` regardless of the provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain in more details why it's not working and what kind of exceptions/error is throwing out, if it is.

At first, you can't `unbox` a string directly to another `Type` (like ObjectQuery).

You just can `unbox` from a base class to an inherited one, vice versa.

The following is something you can do:

```cs
int number = 30;
object obj = number;
number = (int) obj;// if it fails, will throw a cast exception

...

class A
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class B : A
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

class C
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

...

A objectA = new A();
A objectAAndB = new B();
B objectJustB = (B) objectAAndB;
B objectB = (B) A; // It'll throw a cast exception
```

And follows something you can not do:

```cs
A objectA = new A();
B objectB = new B();
C objectC = new C();
A objectC1 = new C(); // It won't compile
C objectC2 = (C) objectA; // It won't compile
C objectC3 = (C) objectB; // It won't compile
A objectA1 = (A) objectC; // It won't compile
B objectB1 = (B) objectC; // It won't compile
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: you can se more on [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)